# Notation of homeomorphism from B(H) to B(K), corresponding to unitary transformation of Hilbert spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, notation, functional-analysis

Let U be a unitary transformation from Hilbert space H to Hilbert space K.

How do you call a *-homomorphism f from B(H) to B(K), defined by $f(a) = U a U^{-1}$?

I'm interested both in a symbol, which can be used in formulas, and a name for it, which can be used in texts or in speech.

Comment: Probably, one can denote this f by $U_*$, or something like that.
It would be great if it was so, because then it would be possible not to invent a new letter for this homomorphism for every U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This homomorphism is often denoted $\mathrm{Ad}(U)$ in the case where $H=K$.  The map $\mathrm{Ad}:\mathcal{U}(H)\to\mathrm{Aut}(B(H))$ is a surjective homomorphism from the unitary group of $H$ to the $*$-automorphism group of $B(H)$ with kernel $\mathbb{T}I$.  For example, this notation is used in Davidson's [*C*-algebras by example*](http://books.google.com/books?id=0TXteNfrzvcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false) and in Raeburn and Williams's [*Morita equivalence and continuous trace C*-algebras*](http://books.google.com/books?id=KV_cC5uYA7EC&lpg=PR1&dq=raeburn%20and%20williams&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false).  The same notation is often used for the corresponding automorphism of the algebra of compact operators on $H$, even though in that case it is not an inner automorphism unless $H$ is finite dimensional.

I don't know whether the same notation is in common use for the case where $H\neq K$.

Answer (score 1):

If $H=K$ and $U$ is a unitary, then $f$ is called an [*inner automorphism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism#Ring_case) of $\mathbb B(H)$,
because it is given by conjugation with a unitary element of your algebra $\mathbb B(H)$ (these are the "obviously existing automorphism").

Some notation (for the group case) is proposed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism#Notation). At least for rings this notation isn't standard, however.

The above naming doesn't nicely generalise to your more general situation and I don't think there's a common name for isomorphisms given by conjugation with a unitary transformation.

Comment: Probably I'm abusing terminology, but by "U is unitary" I mean the following.  
U is a bounded operator such that it has bounded inverse and $U^{-1}=U^*$.

Comment: You were right. I should say "unitary transformation" instead of "unitary operator" in order to express what I mean. The question was corrected.